# printing function and pass into another function

Tags: python

[image]

What does it mean "passing function to other who does it work"? Is it because we need a specify average grade so at first the program will choose A or b etc, and then calculate using the get average?

What if you do the opposite?

And why we use return instead of print? My guess is it is because it has to calculate, or there is another answer?

Comment: I've had a few beers so I'm potentially on a level to understand, but I can't make sense of your question at all sorry.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code as text.

Comment: Please also correct your grammar. This isn't because I'm the grammar-police, but I'm finding it difficult to understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing a "function to another", you are passing the **return value** of one function to another.

Function calls are evaluated from the inside out.  This means that:

1. the value of `lloyd` is evaluated and passed into `get_average()`
2. the return value of `get_average()` is passed into `get_letter_grade()`
3. the return value of `get_letter_grade()` is passed to `print`

And that is what is printed on your screen.

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing functions to anything

Your last line is equivalent to the following

```
lloyd =... 
avg = get_average(lloyd)
print get_letter_grade(avg)
```

You use return instead of print because functions are standalone blocks of code to calculate a result. They have inputs and outputs. Not all functions print values, and printing doesn't produce output to where the function is called, only your terminal